# How to ensure user selected image doesn't change after restart Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a simple sticker widget that allows the user to select one of the stickers upon placing the widget. My problem is that once the device is restarted, the sticker reverts to the default one. How can I ensure that the user selected sticker remains regardless of whether the device is restarted or not? An example or push in the right direction would be very helpful. I'm not looking for anyone to do it for me, just to be educated on how to go about doing that. Thank you.

**EDIT**
*Included Code*

I'm not sure but I think I'm going about this all wrong. I have no clue how to incorporate SharedPreferences the way I have it now. Could someone give me an example of how I should go about doing this with at least one of the images I'm using please?

```
public class SpraycanConfig extends Activity
{
int xawID;
AppWidgetManager xawm;
Context xc;
EditText xinfo;
//EasyTracker easyTracker;

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
 super.onCreate(paramBundle);

 Crashlytics.start(this);

setContentView(R.layout.scconfiglayout);



  this.xc = this;
  Bundle localBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (localBundle != null) {
  this.xawID = localBundle.getInt("appWidgetId", 0);
  }
  for (;;)
  {
    this.xawm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.xc);
    ImageButton localImageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.normal);
View.OnClickListener local1 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.normal);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();
  }
};
localImageButton1.setOnClickListener(local1);
ImageButton localImageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.belton);
View.OnClickListener local2 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.belton);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton2.setOnClickListener(local2);
ImageButton localImageButton3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.gold);
View.OnClickListener local3 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.gold);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton3.setOnClickListener(local3);
ImageButton localImageButton4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hardcore);
View.OnClickListener local4 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.hardcore);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton4.setOnClickListener(local4);
ImageButton localImageButton5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ironlak);
View.OnClickListener local5 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.ironlak);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton5.setOnClickListener(local5);
ImageButton localImageButton6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.krylon);
View.OnClickListener local6 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.krylon);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton6.setOnClickListener(local6);
ImageButton localImageButton7 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mtn94);
View.OnClickListener local7 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.ninetyfour);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton7.setOnClickListener(local7);
ImageButton localImageButton8 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.rusto);
View.OnClickListener local8 = new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
  {
    RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(xc.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, R.drawable.rusto);
    xawm.updateAppWidget(xawID, localRemoteViews);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent();
    localIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", xawID);
    setResult(-1, localIntent);
    finish();

  }
};
localImageButton8.setOnClickListener(local8);

return;

  }

 }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

 }



}
```

Comment: I think you need to save that image in share preference and on every launch you need to check if there is image inside your shared preference used that else start a fresh launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like that:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);

    // get the last chosen sticker
    int sticker = sharedPreferences.getInt("chosenSticker", R.drawable.normal);  //the .normal is the default value in case the user didn't choose one.
    myView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageview, sticker);  //now you can use it


    // store user's choice for example:
    View.OnClickListener local2 = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("chosenSticker", R.drawable.belton);
            editor.apply();

            // your rest of your code here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eliran Kuta. That's exactly what I was looking for. That gives me a better perspective of things. I should be able to get everything working with that example.

Answer (score 3):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) would be your best choice.

Actually you can save that the selected image in any way of storage used in android.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way is to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

This is how you would go about it:

1) Initialize a SharedPreferences object. Use a tag for classification, in case you want to store values that affect different aspects of your app.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Stickers", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2) Retrieve the values associated with it. In your case it could be a URL or an asset id. The function requires a second value that would be returned if the preference has not been set yet.

```
myPrefs.getString("SelectedSticker", "default.jpg");
```

3) Store a new value or replace an existing one.

```
public void setStickerPreference(String stickerURL) {
    // retrieve editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    // save or modify the field
    myPrefsEditor.putString("SelectedSticker", stickerURL);
    // commit changes
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry the code formatting does not seem to be working. I'll try editing it later...

Answer (score 0):

Persist your Image or a logic you can go for to know, whether user has actually changed.

Your question about where to put sharedpreference, well put it in the code function that changes the Image or what you talking about, you can use I/O to write to a temp storage lets say Context.getCacheDir() and you can persist your image there, then in your onResume() also check if that file exist with `File.exist()`

Also remember to delete it when you are done accessing it.